# Having trouble to getting typeaheadjs

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I have gone through typeahead reference site . they given some examples. In that examples , they have not mention , what are the JS need to added to run the sample program. share some examples to understand . it will be very useful to us

Comment: Which typeahead? Bootstrap's, or Typeahead? You've listed both tags. In either case, they are standalone, but at least the Bootstrap one requires the Bootstrap CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to the Bootstrap Typeahead plugin, and not the Twitter Typeahead.js, which has links to examples.
For Bootstrap Typeahead you need either the **bootstrap.js** file - which is already there if you downloaded the full version - or the **bootstrap-typeahead.js** which you can get from the Customize page. And of course the **bootstrap.css**.

Here are some example pages that I found useful:
http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/11/07/getting-more-from-twitter-bootstraps-typeahead-library/
and
http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/typehead.php

The plugin doesn't support ajax, so go to Github and download one of the forks that enable ajax and also add some other functionality.